# Kotlin Koans question regarding HTML builders

Tags: kotlin

I'm currently working on the Kotlin Koans exercises and I have a question regarding lines 17 to 22 in the html.kt file.

It reads as follows:

```
fun <T : Tag> T.set(name: String, value: String?): T {
    if (value != null) {
        attributes.add(Attribute(name, value))
    }
    return this
}
```

Now I understand what this does but what I'm wondering about is why the type parameter was added here. As far as I understand it the generic type here can only be of type Tag so what's the added value of adding the generics syntax here? If I rewrite it to this it also compiles and runs fine:

```
fun Tag.set(name: String, value: String?): Tag {
    if (value != null) {
        attributes.add(Attribute(name, value))
    }
    return this
}
```

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Usually this becomes useful at the point when you make use of the chaining mechanism. 
The generic version returns the input type, so if you input an Table tag, you will also return a Table tag. Keeping this type information allows you to call all methods available in Table, not only Tag.
If you just return Tag the compiler has no way of knowing which subtype of Tag you were working on and you would have to cast if you wanted to do any Table-specific operation on the instance.

Comment: Thanks Roland, that makes sense!